# recyclerview not rendering to screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have the following XML file -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E0E0E0 "
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".fragments.CountriesListFragment">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:title="Countries" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_countries_list_countries_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:listitem="@layout/country_viewholder" />


</LinearLayout>
```

and the following fragment -

```kotlin
class CountriesListFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_countries_list) {


    private lateinit var countriesViewModel: CountriesListViewModel
    private lateinit var countriesAdapter: CountriesListAdapter
    private var countriesList = mutableListOf<CountryEntity>()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        initViewModel()
        init()
    }


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.country_list_menu, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    private fun initViewModel(){
        countriesViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CountriesListViewModel::class.java)
        countriesViewModel.fetchAllCountries(object : CountriesRepository.CountryFetchCallback {
            override fun onFetchError(reason: String) {
                Toast.makeText(context, reason, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }

    private fun init() {
        countriesAdapter = CountriesListAdapter(countriesList)
        countriesRecyclerview.adapter = countriesAdapter
        countriesRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
        countriesRecyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        countriesViewModel.getAllCountries().observe(requireActivity(), Observer { countryList ->
            countriesList.addAll(countryList)
            countriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
    }
}
```

edit -

my adapter -

```kotlin
class CountriesListAdapter(private val countriesList: List<CountryEntity>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CountryViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CountryViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(App.context!!).inflate(R.layout.country_viewholder, parent, false)
        return CountryViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int  = countriesList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CountryViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(countriesList[position])
    }

}
```

my viewholder xml -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/country_viewholder_native_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:text="Country native name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/country_viewholder_country_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:text="Country name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/country_viewholder_area"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:text="Area" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/country_viewholder_country_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

the activity holding the fragment -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CountriesListActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/app_navigation" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

thw navigation graph -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/app_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/countriesListFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/countriesListFragment"
        android:name="com.countriesborders.fragments.CountriesListFragment"
        android:label="fragment_countries_list"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_countries_list">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_countriesListFragment_to_countryBordersFragment"
            app:destination="@id/countryBordersFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/countryBordersFragment"
        android:name="com.countriesborders.fragments.CountryBordersFragment"
        android:label="fragment_country_borders"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_country_borders" />
</navigation>
```

For some reason, the data is not being rendered into the screen. I really have no idea what is causing it, but I am stuck clueless what is happening.

I have tried adding manually hardcoded values into the list but it did not help at all.

Any idea?

Comment: Just a note here, but you probably want to use match_parent for recycler view height. Also, if something doesn't work while using live data, the easiest thing to check is to see if the data is actually changed or not. If the observer for countriesViewModel.getAllCountries() is called, then the issue might be with the recycler view, but if it isn't, then the issue is most likely with the live data mechanism.  Can you add a log to check this case?

Comment: I have checked the livedata - the data does indeed arrive and the list is being filled. `OnBindViewHolder` is being called and `bind()` function is being called. So everything seems correct but the list is not being rendered into the screen

Comment: Could you post the adapter and maybe the recycler view item layout? Maybe you return 0 for getItemCount in adapter?

Comment: `countriesRecyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)`

Comment: at first debug. check list size

Comment: I have printed the list size into the screen -  I have 0 items at the beginning and than 250 items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two conflicting dimensions in your layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

As you can see, the most inner one is instructing the system to draw the items matching the parent height, but the parent layout is saying to wrap its content (and they result in a 0 height in the end). If you change the inner one to match_parent, it will work and the items will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks god. I would have not solved this in a year.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, you could probably remove the outer most LinearLayout since it has only another LinearLayout as a child. Didn't had a good look on it, but it should be doable.